# Headset mic not working with windows installed via bootcamp on macbook pro retina 15"

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, microphone

I bought a headset recently (HyperX Cloud) and i've installed windows via bootcamp, but my mic don't get detected by windows 8.1, but if i use it on my mac partition which has mac os yosemite installed it does. I've got bootcamp v5 drivers and even tried to reinstall them, didn't work

Comment: This may help. Do you have a red light coming from your audio port? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2622620

Answer (score 1):

This may help if you have a red light coming from your audio port, and possibly if you only have partial sound:

support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2622620